# How to get reference to an instance attribute, and modify its value from outside

Tags: python, oop, reference

I'm working on an application in `tkinter`. I have many Entry widgets in UI, and a few classes in app engine. I need to bind tkinter variables of those entries to instances attributes.

i.e.:

```
class Pipe(Variable):
    """class for pipes"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.diameter = 0
        self.variables = {}

pipe1 = Pipe(self)
pipe2 = Pipe(self)
```

I want to bind value from one entry to `pipe1.diameter`, and value from another entry to `pipe2.diameter`. I'm doing it by a `trace` function, where is `lambda` statement, pointing to a function, which identifies entry, and, using a dictionary proper for each instance, pass a value from entry to dictionary value. Dictionaries are produced like here, and then passed as instance attribute:

```
def pipe1_vars(object_):
    variables = {
        'ui_variable_name_for_pipe1_diameter': [object_.diameter]
    }
    return variables

def pipe2_vars(object_):
    variables = {
        'ui_variable_name_for_pipe2_diameter': [object_.diameter]
    }
    return variables

pipe1.variables = pipe1_vars(pipe1)
pipe2.variables = pipe2_vars(pipe2)
```

Unfortunately, `Variable` class method, assigning value, isn't working properly.

```
class Variable():
    def set_var_value(variable_name, value):
        ui_variable = tkinterbuilder.get_variable(variable_name)
        self.variables[variable_name][0] = value
        if ui_variable.get() != value:
            ui_variable.set(value)
```

Obviously `self.variables[variable_name][0]` is something different than `self.diameter`. The dictionary value is changing, but `instance.diameter` stays the same.

How can I pass a real instance attribute to this method, instead of a copy in a dictionary value?

I'm assuming it is important to my app, to build something working as those dictionaries, because i need to bind similar attributes of different pipes to different entries - so it's have to be defined outside of a `Pipe()` class. I don't know if I should change dictionary to something else, or maybe should I rebuild those functions, building dictionary. I've run out of ideas, what to ask google.

Code is much complex, I've posted only most important elements, but if any other details are important, please note in comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of `Pipe` attributes is small, make them properties, and when you create a `Pipe` object, pass it the corresponding tk binded variable:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, ttk

root = Tk()
var_e1 = tk.StringVar()

def print_e1():
    print(var_e1.get())

def inc_e1():
    var_e1.set(int(var_e1.get())+1)

class Pipe():
    def __init__(self, tkvar):
        self.tkvar = tkvar
        tkvar.set('')

    @property
    def diameter(self):
        return self.tkvar.get()

    @diameter.setter
    def diameter(self, value):
        self.tkvar.set(value)

e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var_e1)
b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Print e1', command=print_e1)
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Increment e1', command=inc_e1)

e1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
b1.pack()
b2.pack()

p1 = Pipe(var_e1)
p1.diameter = 200

root.mainloop()
```